# My python enviroment in vscode is messed up, how do i delete everything related to it and start clean?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation

I'm having a lot of problems with my vscode that im trying to use for my python course (can't install pandas, paths are all messed up, different library problems etc). I would like to reset EVERYTHING, install vscode again and now properly set it up. How do i do that?

I tried uninstalling vscode and installing it again, but all the underlying files are still there.

Comment: Did you tried removing python and installing it again?

Comment: Is your python environment a virtual environment? If so do you have a requriements.txt file or a pyproject.toml file?

Comment: Fixing python is the key not fixing vscode. What platform are you using?

Comment: Please precise what do you mean by "environment", (e.g. files, conda-pip etc)
VSCode is an IDE (a software platform at the end of the day, re-installing it won't clean underlying mess)

Comment: I'm on a mac. I also deleted my python files (althought im not sure if there are other files there besides the ones i deleted). I tried installing pythong through their website, but also inside VScode with the python extension. I'm very new to this and most of the terminology you're using (such as conda-pip, pyproject.toml etc) are a foreign language to me.

Comment: @LjubaCeranic I may serve you to learn a little more about these things. See articles such as [Python Virtual Environment Setup on Mac OSX - Easiest Way](https://www.studytonight.com/post/python-virtual-environment-setup-on-mac-osx-easiest-way)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely uninstall vscode and start everything again, follow the document below:

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall*

If you are not familiar with the Python environment, please refer to the following documents.

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments*

The simplest is to [create a new virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_creating-environments) and then start in it.